# c# Enumerable.Sum Method doesn't support ulong type

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

For c# `Enumerable.Sum<TSource> Method (IEnumerable<TSource>, Func<TSource, Int64>)` doesn't support `ulong` type as the return type of the Mehtonf unless I cast ulong to `long`.

```
public class A
{
  public ulong id {get;set;}

} 




publec Class B
{
    public void SomeMethod(IList<A> listOfA)
    {
        ulong result = listofA.Sum(A => A.Id);
    }
}
```

The compliler would throw two errors:

1. [image]
2. [image]

   unless i do

`ulong result = (ulong)listOfA.Sum(A => (long)A.Id)`

Is there anyway to solve that without casting? Thanks!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You could use `Aggregate` instead:

```
ulong result = listOfULongs.Aggregate((a,c) => a + c);
```

Or in your specific case:

```
ulong result = listOfA.Aggregate(0UL, (a,c) => a + c.Id);
```

You should also consider if you really should be using an unsigned value type in the first place.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to be a nice way of solving the problem. The reason i am using `ulong` is because an Id can't be negative. Do you think i really should use `long` instead?

Comment: @Z.Z. - If you're not dealing with negative numbers and the result of your sum exceeds `9,223,372,036,854,775,807`, but doesn't exceed `18,446,744,073,709,551,615` then `ulong` is a good idea. Otherwise `long` is a perfectly fine choice.

Answer (score 10):

You could write your own extension method to provide the overload for `ulong` since it's not provided as part of the BCL:

```
public static ulong Sum<TSource>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, ulong> summer)
{
    ulong total = 0;

    foreach(var item in source)
      total += summer(item);

    return total;
}
```

Comment: Nice answer, but this gives a compiler error "CS0165 Use of unassigned local variable 'total'". You need to definitely assign `total`.

Comment: Thanks for that, I was writing the code in SO and didn't run it through a compiler, I'll update it.

Comment: Thanks for answering! Extension method seems to be a nice solution!

Comment: @PhilipPittle - Do you have/use LINQPad?

Comment: @Enigmativity - Not on this machine :(

Comment: @PhilipPittle - I guess that means you use it on other machines and you know how good it is, among other things, for testing code.