C# Dictionary does not contain a definition for sum when using ulong
I have a Dictionary<string, DemoRecord> with DemoRecord having a field Size.
I now want to calculate the sum of all sizes using LINQ. Here's the example
public record DemoRecord(string Name, ulong Size);

public class DemoStackOverflow()
{
    public ulong GetSum(Dictionary<string, DemoRecord> data)
    {
        return data.Sum(x => x.Value.Size); // Syntax error
    }
}

However, Visual Studio highlights the Sum method with an error message for which I cannot comprehend the problem.

When explicitly specifying the generic type, it just highlights the data variable with another error message.

Is this impossible? It really seems like a trivial LINQ method. Visual Studio itself suggest that Sum exists on the Dictionary. Why is ulong the culprit?

EDIT
This code is not a problem when using int's


This has been asked before. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35612997/c-sharp-enumerable-sum-method-doesnt-support-ulong-type

ulong totalSize = myDictionary.Aggregate((s, a) => s + a);

You need to sum up the values in the dictionary like this.
long totalSize = myDictionary.Values.Sum(record => (long)record.Size);

Sum also doesn't support ulong, so that's why you also need to convert to long or to decimal, if long happens to be too short.

An ulong might not fit in a long.

@Magnus Yes of course.  I clarified by adding decimal as an option.
